# Display block on email order confirmation only when check / money order

Tags: email, email-templates, sales-order

I want to display a li in the order confirmation email only when the customer selected check / money order.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
Here is not so pretty solution, but it works.

You need to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` method and pass an additional parameter to the e-mail template.

To do this, you need to create a custom module (`Vendor_Module`), add this inside the `config.xml` of the module inside the `<global><models>` tag.

```
<sales>
    <rewrite>
        <order>Vendor_Module_Model_Order</order>
    </rewrite>
</sales>
```

Then create the file `Vendor/Module/Model/Order.php` with this code:

```
<?php 
class Vendor_Module_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order 
{
    public function sendNewOrderEmail()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

        if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
            return $this;
        }
        // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
        $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
        $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

        // Start store emulation process
        $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

        try {
            // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
            $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
            $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
            $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // Stop store emulation process
            $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
            throw $exception;
        }

        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }

        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
            // Add bcc to customer email
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
            }
        }
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

        // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($email);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }
        }
        //this needs to be added
        if ($this->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'checkmo') {
            $checkmoComment = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Your message here');
        }
        else {
            $checmoComment = '';
        }
        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $this,
                'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                'checkmo_comment' => $checkmoComment //this needs to be added
            )
        );
        $mailer->send();

        $this->setEmailSent(true);
        $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The code above is basically the original `sendNewOrderEmail` method with a few additional lines. I commented those lines with `this needs to be added`.

Now you should be able to add in the e-mail template this variable  `{{var checkmo_comment}}` where you want your text to appear.